# video to audio converter python run time error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I'm trying to build video to audio converter, but it shows run time error after receiving video link as input. Can anyone tell me what the error is,

```
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube
import os
def main():
    video_url = input('Enter YouTube video URL: ')

    if os.name == 'nt':
        path = os.getcwd() + '\\'
    else:
        path = os.getcwd() + '/'

    name = pytube.extract.video_id(video_url)
    YouTube(video_url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(filename=name)
    location = path + name + '.mp4'
    renametomp3 = path + name + '.mp3'

    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('ren {0} {1}'.format(location, renametomp3))
    else:
        os.system('mv {0} {1}'.format(location, renametomp3))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes  Perhaps your video isn't up any more?

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to look at pathlib.Path rather than munging strings, and the wisdom now is to use subprocess.run rather than os.system.  However none of this is related to your error

Comment: providing current link!